# iOS - Firebase Phone Auth Not Working in Production

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have went through the firebase SDK for setting up Phone Auth for iOS and I have created the appropriate profile and certificate on Apple Connect to receive Push Notifications but I'm having a problem with getting the Phone Auth to work properly on Production. For some reason, it works perfectly while running code with xCode (both Simulator and real device) but after I upload it to App Store Connect it gives me the following error after entering a phone number: "Something went wrong. Please try again".

I have already updated my Firebase Console with the appropriate APNs Authentication Key so I'm at a loss to what to do next. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!